# Disable automatic landing page in JB4A SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios, mobilepush-ios, push-notification

Is there a way to disable automatically OpenDirect handling from SDK when there's no `ExactTargetOpenDirectDelegate` set?

The problem is when the app launches because of push notifications, `didReceiveOpenDirectMessageWithContents:payload` method is called twice, once from `application(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)` method and once from `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)` method.

One other note is why is `ETPush.pushManager` calls open direct delegate on app launch instead of relying on push notification delegate? This is causing the open direct to be called twice unless I'm missing something here or there's a config that this behavior can be modified.

Answer (score 0):

@mani, automatic open direct handling is the default in the SDK unless the delegate has been set; there is not a means to control that aspect.

To address the "notification opened on cold launch" handling (as you describe) it would be suggested to set a value if there is a `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` launch option to defer the processing of that notification to the call to userNotificationCenter:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:

Passing the notification off to the SDK only once is necessary in this case (and may also allow you the time to conditionally set your open direct delegate).